# Microsoft Azure Firewall

Tags: azure, port, iptables, centos6

Description: 
I have built a Centos 6.5 on VM on Microsoft Azure,
I need to open 5060 for using Asterisk.
I first enabled endpoint 5060 on VM, 
and then I added rule for accepting port 5060 in iptables in Centos 6.5
I saved it and restarted it.

When I telnet 5060 from external, connection refused.

Then I disabled the iptables and tried again, very wired connection refused neither.

That is to say, My iptables on Centos 6.5 dose not work at all. even if I closed it, I still can not reach other port except port 22.

Can someone help me out ? 
Very appreciate !

Michael

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 4 places the port may be closed

1. Your ISP
2. The Endpoint on Azure. Make sure that is open
3. Firewall on the OS, e.g. IPTables in your case
4. The Application

**Step 1**

Allow EVERYTHING through IPTables. Basically take down your firewall. Try telnet now. If it works it is an IPtable misconfiguration.

**Step 2**

Telnet on your own VM to see if the application has the port open. If yes, then it is a firewall blocking. If no, your application isn't opening the port.

**Step 3**

Use http://www.canyouseeme.org/ to check ports are open outside of your ISP.

If this works, its your ISP. If it doesn't it is your endpoint configuration on Azure.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, But when I did as step2, I can not telnet on VM. So I guess it must be my application isn't opening any port except 22 (I tried 80 or 5060, both opened on Azure)

Do you know how to solve it next ?

Best regards Michael

Comment: Hi thanks ! I have solved this because I did not run any application on those ports so I cant telnet them .  Thank you again